# Getting Started with POP3 Using Boost Asio

Tags: c++, sockets, boost-asio

To help myself learn socket programming, I made a very simple SMTP client (see code below), using some code from the the [Wt SMTP Library](http://www.webtoolkit.eu/wt/doc/reference/html/group__mail.html)

As an exercise, I thought I would take a shot at implementing a POP3 client.  Using the [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Post_Office_Protocol) as a reference, it looked as if you must simply connect to the server on port 110 and send commands (just like SMTP connects on port 25 and sends commands).

However, I have so far been unable to even connect, and basically just timeout in the `get_response()` every time.  I tried connecting to `pop.gmail.com` with no luck.

I don't believe that you need to send any user/password/other information when the connection is first established?  I expected to receive something along the lines of `+OK POP3 Server Ready` once I connect, and I can then send the `USER` and `PASS` commands.

My question is: Am I missing something during the connection phase?  Am I trying to connect to a bad host (gmail)?  If so, is there a better host than `pop.gmail.com` with which I can test?  Or am I going about this entirely wrong?

```
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>

#include <boost/asio.hpp>

using boost::asio::ip::tcp;

int main()
{
    boost::asio::io_service io_service;
    tcp::socket socket(io_service);

    tcp::resolver resolver(io_service);
    tcp::resolver::query query("localhost", "25");   // Change this for POP3
    tcp::resolver::iterator endpt_iter = resolver.resolve(query);

    boost::system::error_code erc = boost::asio::error::host_not_found;
    while(erc && endpt_iter != end)
    {
        socket.close();
        socket.connect(*endpt_iter++, erc);
    }

    if(erc) { socket.close(); return }

    std::cout << get_response(socket) << std::endl;     // 220 <my-host-name> ESMTP Postfix
    send(socket, "EHLO localhost\r\n");
    std::cout << get_response(socket) << std::endl;     // 250-<my-host-name>

    return 0;
}

std::string get_response(tcp::socket& socket)
{
    boost::asio::streambuf response;
    for(;;)
    {
        std::string msg;
        boost::asio::read_until(socket, response, "\r\n");
        std::istream in(&response);
        std::getline(in, msg);
        return msg;
    }
}

void send(tcp::socket& socket, std::string msg)
{
    boost::asio::write(socket, boost::asio::buffer(msg));
}
```

Comment: this isn't a forum, we generally don't use salutations in questions

Answer (score 0):

Gmail requires SSL/TLS encryption on its POP3 and SMTP connections.

For POP3, you have to connect to port 995 and initiate an SSL/TLS handshake immediately upon connecting.  Then you can read the server's initial `+OK` greeting from, and send commands to, the encrypted connection.

For SMTP, you have a couple of choices:

1. connect to port 465. Initiate an SSL/TLS handshake immediately upon connecting.  Read the `+OK` greeting from, and send all commands to, the encrypted connection.
2. connect to port 587.  Read the `+OK` greeting from, and send `EHLO` and `STARTTLS` commands to, the unencrypted connection.  Initiate the SSL/TLS handshake.  Send a new `EHLO` command, and other commands, to the encrypted connection.